# how to query using linq for the a scenario that has multiple dropdown , text and date filed

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am doing a search in the db using linq and my table in db is as follows

[image]

My search has following 4 drop downs 3 text boxes and 2 date fields:

- location(dd)
- name(text)
- email/phone(text)
- fromdate (date)
- todate(date)
- field1(dd)
- field2(dd)
- field3(dd)
- search(btn)

---

- the location  points the location column in the table
- the name  search point firstname and lastname column in the table
- the email/phone points email/phone column in the table
- the field 1 points field 1 column in the table
- the field 2 points field 1 column in the table
- the field 3 points field 1 column in the table
- the fromdate and to date point fromdate in the db

i need to write a linq query which satisfies if any dropdown or textbox are left empty it should bring all the respective values from the table.
If from date is given and to date is not given to date should be made as 30 days from todays date like wise if from date is not given and to date is given from date should be -30 days from today

what is tried is

```
var searchlist = (from i in _context.EmployeeBasicInformations

      where i.FormCurrentStatus == "CanditateCreated"
      
      &&(i.EmployeeFirstName.Contains(Namess)) || (i.EmployeeLastName.Contains(Namess))
      || (i.EmployeeAadharCardNumber.Contains(search)) || (i.EmployeePanCardNumber.Contains(search))
      || (i.EmployeeEmail.Contains(search)) || (i.EmployeePersonalNumber.Contains(search)) && j.LocationId == Location
      select new EmployeeBasicInformationVM
      {
         
      }).ToList();


Console.WriteLine(searchlist.ToString());

return Json(searchlist);
```

Comment: "write a linq query which satisfies if any dropdown or textbox are left empty it should bring all the respective values from the table" If they are  empty, how to bring all the respective values from the table ?